# Retrieve song paths from playlist provider?

Tags: android, path, media, playlist

Is it possible to retrieve SDcard paths for each song in a playlist, using the MediaStore.Playlist providers?  The closest I see are values for the name of the song... is there any data member which includes the full path?

(I'm attempting to create an app which writes Android's internal playlists to physical files on the SDcard.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.  Evidently it's the DATA member.

I originally interpreted DATA as an abstract representation of the actual data file.  However, the DATA member of the Playlists provider actually stores the exact filesystem path, and now I've answered my own question!  :)